# I see the response body in chrome developer tools, but unable to retrieve it inside Front End

Tags: http, grails, response

I am currently working in a project where I need to send a response from grails back end to ReactJs front End. I was able to send the response from grails controller using "response" but unable to extract the response body on the ReactJs side. I tried  checking in the following and found null value or undefined.

response.content, response.body

I see the response I sent back from grails in chrome web developer tools "Network" tab. but unable to find out which field of response object actually has it. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

My http request.

```
post: function(url, item) {

    return fetch(baseUrl + url, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: item
    }).then(function(response) {

        alert(response);
        return response ;
    });

},
```

grails

```
    response << "there is an error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `render 'there is an error'`
Or if you need to render JSON:

```
render [someKey: 'there is an error'] as JSON
```

To understand how grails controllers and views work read [this](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-starting-with-controllers/) simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried content-type: 'application/json'